# I have created 5 ssis packages and i need to execute them by using file watcher

Tags: c#, ssis

I have created 5 ssis packages and i need to execute them by using file watcher which watches for the files in a folder and execute the appropriate package. Files name are like this *****_201307.txt,******_201308.txt etc which changes according to month. Here is my code

```
private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    // Specify what is done when a file is changed, created, or deleted.
    //Console.WriteLine("File: " & e.FullPath & " " & e.ChangeType)

    //logger.Info("Realtime file watcher activity: change type [" + e.ChangeType + "] file [" + e.Name + "]");
    Console.WriteLine("Realtime file watcher activity: change type [" + e.ChangeType + "] file [" + e.Name + "]");

    if (_watcherActivityList.Count > 10000)
    {
        //logger.Warn("Realtime file watcher activity list is over 10,000 items, clearing list");
        _watcherActivityList.Clear();
    }
    else
    {
        //under 10,000 items
    }

    _watcherActivityList.Add(e.ChangeType + "|" + e.FullPath);

    if (e.ChangeType == WatcherChangeTypes.Created)
    {
        /*** THIS IS WHERE YOU'LL CALL YOUR SSIS PACKAGE ***/
    }
```

Can some one post the code here /*** THIS IS WHERE YOU'LL CALL YOUR SSIS PACKAGE ***/

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17358630/how-to-execute-multiple-ssis-packages-from-c-sharp

Comment: no i need to execute package according to the incoming file name

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest one these methods to you:

1. Create a stored procedure and call it with the filename as parameter. In the stored procedure put the filename into a table and adjust your SSIS package to read the filename from that table. After you wrote the filename into the table start the SSIS package from within the procedure with the `sp_start_job` command.
2. Write the filename into a textfile and adjust your SSIS package to read the filename from there. Then just start the SSIS package from a `Process`.
3. Start the SSIS package from a `Process` and provide a user variable as parameter. The call would look like this:

> dtexec /file SSISPackage.dtsx /Set \Package.Variables[User::Filename].Properties[Value];\"myFile.txt\"